# How to add Media Query in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

This is the jQuery code that I am using in my WordPress website, and it's working fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).on("click",".selected",function() {
$('.wvg-single-gallery-image-container').css('display','none');
})  
});
```

I just want the code to stop working at the screen width of 766, on 766 the code does not have to work.

Let me know if there is something that can make this possible.

Thanks,
Abdullah

Comment: cant you just hide the ".selected" component with css media query?

Comment: Try, not working.

Comment: I don't want the ".selected" to be hide just wants that function to stop working on 766px.

Comment: You can't use media queries with inline styles on elements. What you *can* do is use a media query in a `<style>` block (or imported CSS file) and a class name to switch the styling on and off based on screen width.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How about `$(window).width()`, this returns a pixel value, and you can then use an `if` statement to `.hide()` the element.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks,

I am not so pro on jQuery can you adjust those things that you mentioned in my code and just send here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(document).on("click", ".selected", function() {
    if($(window).width() < 766){
      $('.wvg-single-gallery-image-container').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

If the document is not very wide, less than 766, the button will perform the action. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mediaMatch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to test against a media query…

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 766px)')) {
    $('.wvg-single-gallery-image-container').css('display','none');
}
```

…but that approach isn't a great one. Consider what would happen if the user resized the window after the JS had run. The inline style you are adding would still be there, but based on the wrong window size.

Instead, use JS to add and remove *classes* from elements. Then use those classes in your CSS with media queries.

```
$('.wvg-single-gallery-image-container').addClass('a-suitably-semantic-class-name);
```